# Poll for new sub-folders inside a directory using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to write a camel route for watching new subfolders inside a directory. There is an input directory to which the daily website feed comes as a new sub-folder with a name as a date. Every sub-folder uploaded has a similar structure. I want to pull the new date folder whenever it is uploaded.

Also, the camel provides readlock but it works only on Files. Is there a way to put readlock on the folder?

- inputDirectory

  - 11/12/2020

    - products
    - taxonomy
  - 12/12/2020

    - products
    - taxonomy
  - 13/12/2020

    - products
    - taxonomy
  - etc..

I tried using 'recursive=true' but no luck with that (we cannot use include and antInclude as we are dealing with a folder here). I know a camel is mostly for files but want to know if the above requirement can be met with the camel.

I'm pretty new to Camel and please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` option can also be used for folder names. So you can write a `GenericFileFilter` implementation that checks the folder name if it matches todays date.